# Why the TCP server socket is closed unexpectedly?

Tags: c, sockets

I have created a Win32 server-client application, where many clients connect to a single server, send queries and `recv` responses.

It works fine in many installations, but the connection is closed in some others. Both client and server report that the connection is closed by the remote host. The sequence of socket operations after the connection is created is this:

```
Client: sends query Q1 (by calling send)
Server: recvs query Q1 and sends R1
Client: recvs R1
Client: sends query Q2
Server: recvs query Q2 and sends R2
Client: recvs R2
and so on
```

In some networks, after a period of time, for example, 1 hour or 10 minutes,

```
    Client: Sends Q(n) successfully
    Server: recvs SOCKET_ERROR and my code exits thread. 
//unexpected
   WSAGetLastError() at server returns 10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
    Client: recvs SOCKET_ERROR. 
WSAGetLastError() at client also returns 10054
```

In server there is one thread for each client. The server has negligible delay before responding.

Why does the function `recv()` at the server side return SOCKET_ERROR? Who closes the socket?
Edit: I updated the question and put the WSAGetLastErrorCode() return value.
Why -1? What is wrong with this question?

Comment: If you are using windows, you are probably using winsock2 right? if so, what is the WSAGetLastError return code? The client is probably exiting without closing the connection and that causes your server to receive a non-fatal socket error, but you exit anyways

Comment: You're jumping to conclusions. SOCKET_ERROR does **not** mean that the peer closed the connection. Nor does it close any sockets. You need to ;post the *actual* error as returned by `WSAGetLastError()`.

Comment: I didn't conclude that. I forgot to report the error code. WSAGetLastError() return 10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Comment: At both client and server?

Comment: @MR_ABDOLAHZADEH -1 because people don't like when you don't provide the source code. Minimal working example to reproduce the problem

Comment: Yes. Both at server and client recv() returns SOCKET_ERROR (WSA ERROR 10054)

Comment: @Pedro Sassen Veiga Please remove -1 so that people threat it a proper question and respond me.

Comment: @Pedro Sassen Veiga The source code is too big to post. If necessary, I can simplify and post it. And please note that the problem occurs in some networks, not all of them. so It's hard to reproduce the error. please remove -1

Comment: @MR_ABDOLAHZADEH wasn't me that downvoted, sorry i can't remove. I responded your question, if the answer is wrong please say why is this not what you are looking for and post your code

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the documentation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

10054 Error

> Connection reset by peer.
>
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. This normally results if the peer application on the remote host is suddenly stopped, the host is rebooted, the host or remote network interface is disabled, or the remote host uses a hard close (see setsockopt for more information on the SO_LINGER option on the remote socket). This error may also result if a connection was broken due to keep-alive activity detecting a failure while one or more operations are in progress. Operations that were in progress fail with WSAENETRESET. Subsequent operations fail with WSAECONNRESET.

You are probably exiting your program when you receive this error, so check for that error and do the logic to delete the client from the clients lists or another structure you may have and finish its thread, but you don't need to close the socket.

Here is the recv() return value documentation

> Return value
>
> If no error occurs, recv returns the number of bytes received and the buffer pointed to by the buf parameter will contain this data received. If the connection has been gracefully closed, the return value is zero.
> Otherwise, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError.

Comment: No, None of these occur. My logs show that before beeing forcibly closed by the host, all send and recv call complete successfully, (they return the count of bytes sent or recieved).

Comment: You are looking at all error codes, i posted the one that occurs to you 10054, so that must be what is happening. But is really hard to know without the code. We can make predictions but not know for sure.

Comment: No, None of these occur. My logs show that before beeing forcibly closed by the host, all send and recv call complete successfully, (they return the count of bytes sent or recieved). The server program is alive and logs the error, and new clients can connect. The client program is alive and logs the error and shows a proper message box. No program stops, No host is rebooted. Please not that Both server and client applications are alive and log the WSAGetLastError result.

Comment: What you mean by disabling network interface? The only thing I should consider is SO_LINGER, of which I havn't considered yet. all operations are completed Before getting 10054. I don't get WSAENETRESET at all. The server deletes the client from clients list deleting it's objects and exiting the thread. (There is one thread for each client).

Comment: I'll try to simplify both server and client app's, sending, recving and logging very simple data. and post the code here

Comment: @MR_ABDOLAHZADEH in your question you clearly state that recvreturns SOCKET_ERROR and then you say that it returns the bytes received? i am confused.

Comment: I state that send() and recv() return bytes sent or recved before sending Q(n). Client Sends Q(n) succesfully(returning count of bytes). Recv at R(n) returns SOCKET_ERROR at both client and server, width error code 10054. Pardon for my typing mistakes. I press ENTER two much

Comment: @MR_ABDOLAHZADEH if you are going to try to simplify your code and post do it in another question, people won't give this one attention anymore because is heavily commented. Hope you can solve your issue. Also try to write a well explained and complete example. :)